# Ruby on Rails - Calendar Display

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We want to create a calendar view in a room scheduling application.  The outcome we want is to have hours open (variable depending on day) across the top of the grid and the names of the rooms down the left side of the grid.  The body would be populated with bookings for that day.  The visual we're seeking is similar to the "Weekly Builder" plugin for Rails (http://dmix.ca/2009/06/weeklybuilder-a-weekly-calendar-plugin-for-rails/).

We've tried using CSS to create variably-sized images, but this isn't working out.  Are there any plugins available or other ways anyone can think of to accomplish this kind of visual?

Thanks

Comment: There is a neat Railscast doing this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars

Answer (score 0):

Full calendar is what you are looking for. It has an "Scheduler" utility which can be used just for what you are mentioning. I've used it myself and it's well documented and easy to use: https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/

[image]

You can create events which occupy multiple rooms, specify working hours, create and resize events by dragging, etc.

Just download the utility: https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/download/. Remember to place the "node_modules" directory under vendor/assets